# How to use GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY to get attributes of all the tables in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to display table names and concatenate table attributes i.e. column names in a table.

I am using the following query.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bysykkel' 
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

But I am not able to get column names. I have tried `TABLE_COLUMNS` but I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html) table to get column names:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bysykkel'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```